# Check remote URL for javascript snippet

Tags: javascript, ajax

My application interacts with my users' websites via a javascript snippet that they paste into their site....like Google Analytics, Stripe, AppInsights...etc.

I'd like for my web app to be able to ping the remote site, to verify the pasted snippet exists.  If it does exists, I'd like the remote javascript method to respond.

I feel like this should be easy but I'm having trouble putting it all together.  For the remote script, I made it so it checked the querystring for a trigger value...if found, it would execute a 'self check' and respond.

I wasn't quite sure how to make the script respond to my ajax call and I also didn't necessarily like the idea of checking the querystring every window.load

Can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest a more elegant approach?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to think it all the other way around. How these kinds of scripts are working is that they have an API key generated just for that website and when the website is loaded it is the JavaScript code snipped that does send the API key to the API generated server to show that the snippet is available and gives the information about the page that it is loaded in.

This way you don't need to check if the snipped is available in a website. Of course if you need consistent dialog with the snipped you have to use Web Socket or other ways of communications (for the older browsers like long polling and ...)

For sure not using Web Socket and two-way communication gives the trust to the user that you are not doing any malicious work underneath and the first approach should help you enough. But if you persist on using the two-way communication please see [MDN WebSocket documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) .

The first approach (not using two-way communication) is just an ajax call you can do it with JQuery: [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), or do not use any library just pure JavaScript which is [John Shipp on Vanilla JS AJAX requests](http://www.johnshipp.com/pure-javascript-ajax-request-rockin-js-old-school/) .

Comment: ya I don't really need any two way communication...just a one time thing, like a button or something that the new user can tap to verify that the necessary integrations have been set up properly.  Its all about peace of mind...if they've done it incorrectly, it could be days or weeks (or never) before the improper setup is discovered.

Comment: But you see, you don't need a button. the snipped code will be loaded in the user's website and you can have a function in it that is called when the website is loaded and the function will send a message to the server (with ajax) that says it has been initialized.

Comment: marking this as the answer, it doesn't really fit the flow like I was picturing but what I did was make the script watch for a querystring variable to trigger it send the message to my server.  On my side, I override the method to allow * cross origin calls, and either with a button or whatever, I can just ping the user's web page with the trigger var which then causes the snippet to ping home  (hope that makes sense)